Ошибка пуша Swiper.js на gitHub
Работаю с шаблоном create-react-app.
Возникла эта ошибка предположительно из-за библиотеки Swiper (Но это не точно)
При пуше билда на github возникает ошибка:
chunk 505 [mini-css-extract-plugin]
Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[4]!./src/components/SliderDisplay/SliderDisplay.module.scss
despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[4]!./src/components/RoomItem/RoomItem.module.scss
   - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s)

chunk 505 [mini-css-extract-plugin]
Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[4]!./node_modules/swiper/swiper.scss
despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[4]!./src/components/RoomItem/RoomItem.module.scss
   - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s)

chunk 505 [mini-css-extract-plugin]
Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[4]!./node_modules/swiper/modules/navigation.scss
despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[4]!./src/components/RoomItem/RoomItem.module.scss
 * couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s)

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Вот мое подключение:
import { Navigation } from 'swiper/modules';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

import 'swiper/scss';
import 'swiper/scss/navigation';

const Rooms = () => {


const swiperRef = useRef(null);

  const roomsData = getRooms();
  const [roomIndex, setRoomIndex] = useState(0);

  const { showPrevSlide, showNextSlide } = useSlider(
roomIndex,
roomsData,
setRoomIndex,
swiperRef
  );
  return (

<section className={rooms}>
  <div className={container}>
    <h2 className={subtitle}>номера</h2>

    <MediaQuery maxWidth={1023}>
      <Swiper
        modules={[Navigation]}
        spaceBetween={50}
        slidesPerView={1}
        navigation
        pagination={{ clickable: true }}
        scrollbar={{ draggable: true }}
        onSlideChange={swiper => {
          setRoomIndex(swiper.activeIndex);
        }}
        ref={swiperRef}
      >
        {roomsData.map(({ id, title, description, images }) => {
          return (
            <SwiperSlide key={id}>
              <RoomItem
                title={title}
                description={description}
                images={images}
                currentIndex={roomIndex}
              />
            </SwiperSlide>
          );
        })}
      </Swiper>

      <SliderDisplay
        total={roomsData.length}
        current={roomIndex}
        prev={showPrevSlide}
        next={showNextSlide}
      />
    </MediaQuery>

    <MediaQuery minWidth={1024}>
      <div className={roomList}>
        {roomsData.map(({ id, title, description, images }) => {
          return (
            <RoomItem
              key={id}
              title={title}
              description={description}
              images={images}
              currentIndex={roomIndex}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </MediaQuery>
  </div>
</section>
  );
};

